# Сжатие блока с текстом в адаптивной верстке

Tags: html, css, responsive

Как преобразовать данный текст, что бы он сжимался на мобильных устройствах и планшетах?

```css
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1170px;
  left: 40%;
  right: 60%;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}

article {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article class="container1">
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: а для чего для relative сделали left:40% и right:60% ?

Comment: Смотрю и даже представления не имею чего хочет автор  и что он пытался реализовать...

Answer (score 1):

В теге `head` пропишите

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/263017)

Comment: Не отобразился код. Повторюсь: прописан ли мета-тег viewport в head?

Comment: пишите комментарий к вопросу если вы хотите что-то спросить у топикстартера или оформляйте сообщение как ответ. Причитайте, пожалуйста, справочный раздел [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)